# How to show WMS in android with osmdroid

Tags: android, osmdroid

I want show WMS in android with osmdroid. I wrote this code.
But it does not answer. What's wrong? May you guide me.
Thanks

```
public class OSMFragmentTest extends Activity {
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.frafment_layout_test);
        MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.osm_wms_1);
        WMSTileSource wmsTileSource;

        wmsTileSource = new WMSTileSource( "OGC:WMS", new String[]{"http://ows.terrestris.de/osm/wms"},"SRTM30-Hillshade","1.1.1","EPSG:4326","",5 );
        map.setTileSource(wmsTileSource);
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        map.setMultiTouchControls(true);

        GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(37.1, 57.01);
        IMapController mapController = map.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(9);
        mapController.setCenter(startPoint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

osmdroid's support for wms is a bit on the beta side. That said, there's an example in the sample app and there's a wiki page that discusses this.

https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/WMS-Support

and here is the sample app's source, which prompts the user for the server, gets the layers, asks the user which layer to show, then displays it.

https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/samplefragments/tilesources/SampleWMSSource.java

There is another way which is similar to your code, provided that the tile server can server up tiles using a bounds, zoom, and projection, but if requires a bit more work.